# Ask cli to manage deployment of both production and development

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When Using the ask cli with existing skill in production and development version,

How can I use the ask-cli to clone and deploy both versions? 
There is a `--stage live/production` in command reference guide https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#submit-subcommand

I am not sure how to use that flag.

There is a similar question on SO [ASK CLI to deploy to different environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285995/ask-cli-to-deploy-to-different-environments), but I do not want to use a bash script for the task as there is already ask-cli which can help in managing deployments